# My <h1> tag is not looking resolving the style in Firefox but it is in IE

Tags: css

I know that's a switch eh?
But here's the page:
http://www.websitessandiego.com/UBHS/StoriesandPeople/CaseJames&Helena.html

I just cannot figure out why the  tag isn't coming out.  When I look at it using firebug I see all the cufon crap... what is that?

I used a template I bought off of themeforest.net

I've never seen anything like this... any ideas?

thanks

Comment: Sorry mate, that site looks exactly the same in Chrome, Opera, Firefox and IE to me. Try refreshing your firefox or clearing your cache/cookies.

Comment: If you still have a problem try asking on http://doctype.com/questions

Answer (score 1):

turns out - it's cufon.  it's a js script that is over-riding the css.